# Include angular-Material Dependency Bower

Tags: bower, angular-material

In CMD ,following command works fine.

**bower install angular-material**

I am trying to include angular-material dependency in bower.json.I added following line in json file.

```
 "angular-material": "~0.11.1",
```

But this is not working .I am not able to figure it out how to proceed.

[image: building project using npm start]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used following command which updates bower.json file automatically.

**bower install bootstrap --save**

Comment: Is this a not so subtle hint to use Bootstrap instead of Angular Material?

Answer (score 2):

To save the dependecy to the bower.json file you need to add --save.

Try this

**bower install angular-material --save**

--EDIT--

The error message is clear. You don't have git installed.

Bower needs the following to work-

1. node
2. npm
3. git

Verify if you have all these 3 installed like so...

- node -v
- npm -v
- git --version

[image: Bower install]

You can get more info [here](http://bower.io/#install-bower)

Comment: When i do npm start ,bower tries to resolve dependency and fails ..added screenshot