# Unable to install bootstrap using bower

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bower, bower-install

[Please find the image for error information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PGrkE.png)I am trying to install boostrap using bower in windows system.
While I tried to put a command as ***bower install bootstrap -S***
,I am encountered with an error ***bower ENOGIT        git is not installed or not in the PATH***

Please help me out for this issue.

Thanks

Comment: You can find the answer here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32809011/include-angular-material-dependency-bower/32809032#32809032

Comment: Hi Akash, please can you check the snapshot added recently.Please if you can provide me the solution

Answer (score 0):

you should install **Git Bash** First

[Download For Windows](https://git-for-windows.github.io/)

i recommend you to download Bootstrap [Directly](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#download). it's only CSS & JS Files. add those files to your site directory, then you have a Bootstrap Site

good luck

Comment: Hi Arash, I have already installed git(I am able to work on git if I use it from git cmd shell),but I am not able to use it from windows cmd screen.

Answer (score 0):

If you have already installed **git** in your system, then follow the below steps to add the git as `environment variables`. Then you ll able to use git from windows cmd also

Or follow this link - [Adding Git to Windows PATH](http://blog.countableset.ch/2012/06/07/adding-git-to-windows-7-path/)

1. Right-Click on My Computer
2. Click Advanced System Settings link from the left side column
3. Click Environment Variables in the bottom of the window
4. Then under System Variables look for the path variable and click
   edit Add the pwd to git's bin and cmd at the end of the string like
   this:

`;C:\Program Files\Git\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd`